# How to confirm Nginx `deny` is working?

Tags: nginx, firewall, ping

I setup Nginx to deny a specific IP address and would like to confirm that it is working. How can I do this? In principle, I'd like to do something like:

```
ping -from <blocked ip address> <my ip address>
```

and see something about being blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, ping is not a tool you can use to test HTTP. Second, HTTP uses TCP, so you cannot "spoof" an IP address like you're proposing.

Assuming you do not have access to originate HTTP requests from the IP you're trying to block, the only other option is to temporarily block another IP that you **do** have access to. If requests from the test IP are blocked, you can assume that request from the other IP are being blocked as well.